# How to select multiple ID's in a badly designed webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am maintaining a complex web application.

I have a large number of divs which all have **the same ID**.

I know this is totally wrong, and as a matter of fact `document.getElementById()` with that id is going to only produce one match for me.

However I am able to pull out the element that I'm looking for using jQuery (we are on 1.6.2), like this: `$('#bad_id[nonstandard_attr_name=somethingSpecific]')`

Not quite ready to say that this is a "solution".

I'm worried about whether this is reliable or not. Is jQuery really actually gonna search through all the elements that match the ID using a DOM walk? That's probably the only way to get all of them.

Does it filter elements by the other attribute first, and then filter it down by the ID? That would achieve the desired behavior as well, but it would be good to know the order it does this in.

Comment: Nothing is 'reliable' when the source is unreliable. You just do the best you can and hope the band-aid holds long enough.

Comment: the first element with that id is selected i think.

Comment: From a performance standpoint, @OptimusPrime's comment makes sense...jQuery should stop looking for an item with a particular ID once it's found. Perhaps you can first grab a parent element, then `.filter` to the specific ID within that subset of the DOM?

Comment: of course. why would it go on to find the element, which shouldn't exist. @DA.

Comment: 'Each id value must be used only once within a document. If more than one element has been assigned the same ID, queries that use that ID will only select the first matched element in the DOM. This behavior should not be relied on, however; a document with more than one element using the same ID is invalid.', [jQuery ID Selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

Comment: @GopalAggarwal I'm pretty sure he is well aware of that.

Comment: Yes, just making it prominent for future readers.

Comment: why is it that you're able to add new class names or custom attributes to the elements but can't change their IDs?

Comment: Simply select by attribute. e.g. `$('[id="foo"]')`.

Comment: Put a class on all these elements when they're being generated and just select by class. An attribute selector will work but (I think) it will indeed search the entire DOM. Classes in the meantime are indexed.

Comment: Well, it is because of the fact that I should expect only to reliably obtain one single instance of element having that ID, it is surprising to me that i am getting the correct item using this query. So, this is what the question is about. @GeorgeMauer Oh, wouldn't that be nice???!

Comment: @OptimusPrime I'm not sure, but wouldn't selecting a subset of the DOM, then filtering, be independent of the rest of the DOM? If I grab two separate subsets of the DOM, each with a child element sharing the same ID, filtering each subset should work, as it'd be oblivious of the other subset. Is that right?

Comment: I'm not sure why you can't though - those elements are all being generated either on the server or on the client, unless this is a dashboard application which pulls together views from a lot of different sources you don't own, why couldn't you add a class at the source?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you need to select multiple elements with same id you can simply use an attribute selector:

```
$( "[id='myid']" )
```

The attribute selector doesn't look at the attribute key for any semantics like unique ids or such.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZWm3G/

Comment: well, besides the spaces around the quotes :P

Comment: @sgroves that's personal preference. I prefer the spaces around the quotes.

Comment: obviously, i know that. i was just kidding.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell you what jQuery or other dom traversals will do (doubtful it will work always) but you can try this :

```
document.filter = function(attr, val, r) {
    r = r || document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    var s = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
        if(r[i].getAttribute(attr) == val) {
            s.push(r[i]);
        }
    }
    return s;
};

var s = document.filter("nonstandard_attr_name", "somethingSpecific", document.filter("id", "bad_id"));

console.log(s);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KGPFf/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use a selector that will result in something other than `getElementById()` being used should result in consistent results, but make sure you test it with IE8 since IE8 doesn't use `document.querySelectorAll()`.

Using methods such as <strike>.find</strike> .children and .filter should also yield consistent results regardless of the id being unique.

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/gb3Mz/

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. Also, I was thinking that since we already are in a mess, how about using `class` for the role of `id`. I mean give it a class, but use it for only _one_ element.

Comment: i don't see how that would do anything except remove all the benefits of classes

Comment: Yes, classes would be what these id's should be. However I wouldn't even want to think about how much code will break if these id's are swapped for classes.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as seen in comments, my guess was why would it go on searching for any element. Yes
`getElementById` returns the first element and then stops searching, but the same doesn't look right for jQuery. It does return all the elements with that "bad" id.

As can be seen in this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ybPzP/29/)**,

So it is selecting all the elements, this means jQuery doesn't stop at the first element, but goes on searching the entire doument, hence IMO, you may use jQuery to select multiple elements with the common id. There shouldn't be any problem.